# HTML - Align By Prefixes

Tags: html, css

So, I want to make a Page for Q&A, and i want the layout to be like this

```
        Q. Question
        A. Answer
```

But if i use
"align-text:center;"
it will be like this

```
        Q. Long Question
            A. Short Answer
```

The Question is, How do i make it go like this

```
        Q. Long Question
        A. Short Question
```

Edit1, The code im currently working with:

```
.about-text {
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 40px;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: intro-left 4s ease 1.75s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: intro-right 4s ease 1.75s forwards;
       -moz-animation: intro-right 4s ease 1.75s forwards;
         -o-animation: intro-right 4s ease 1.75s forwards;
            animation: intro-right 4s ease 1.75s forwards;
}
```

edit2: The Keyframes

```
@keyframes intro-right {
    0% { transform: translateX(10%); opacity: 0; }
    100% { transform: translateX(0); opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes intro-left {
    0% { transform: translateX(-10%); opacity: 0; }
    100% { transform: translateX(0); opacity: 1; }
}
```

Edit3 The HTML:

```
<div class='about' id='learn-more'>
                <br><br><br>
                <h1 class='about-title'>About and Q&A</h1>
                <br>
                <h2 class='about-text'><strong>Q.</strong> Long Question</h2>
                <p class='about-text'><strong>A.</strong> Short Answer</p>
                <br>
            </div>
```

Comment: My suggestion would be using HTML table if possible.

Comment: @AloHA_ChiCken it gives samiliar results

Comment: It's more easy to style if using table. Trust me :)

Comment: @AloHA_ChiCken don't use tables for layout, unless you are stuck in 1990.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated

use the `display: flex` and `justify content: center` to make it center, also wrap the list inside div, heres the example

```
<div class='about' id='learn-more'>
                <br><br><br>
                <h1 class='about-title'>About and Q&A</h1>
                <br>
                <div class="container-question">
                    <div class="list-question">
                      <p>Q. Long Question</p>
                      <p>A. short Answer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
               
                <br>
            </div>
```

Comment: also the html, not only the css

Comment: if u just want all the text is aligned to left, just dont give any text-align setting on css and it will automatically left-aligned, or maybe you can explain the detail more

Comment: if u want to make list i suggest to use <ul> or <ol> tag

Comment: i want it to be the centered no matter if its un-even (Long and small text align in the same place)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3ejn7s81/17/ is this what u want?

Comment: Yeah, But for some reason when i tried adding it to my code, it turns into

Comment: Q&A Q. Long Question A. Short Answer

Comment: make sure the placement of div, the class, and the css

Comment: This is totally wrong, as this defeats accessibility. Like using a div to make a button instead of using button. It should be made with ul/ol with li's